# grep -l output filenames with spaces

Tags: bash, grep, path, sed

I want to loop over files with

`` for f in `grep -rsl "foo" . `: do sed -i -- "s/foo/bar/g" $f; done; ``

But since filenames contain spaces, a filename is split whenever a space is found.

How can I pass the filename with its spaces to the `do` block?

Comment: [`find . -type f -exec grep -qF foo {} \; -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' {} \;`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212967)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For dealing with difficult file names, it is best to separate the file names with NUL characters.  GNU `grep` supports this with the `--null` option and `xargs` supports this with the `-0` option.  Thus, try:

```
grep --null -rslZ "foo" | xargs -0 sed -i -- "s/foo/bar/g"
```

#### Using a shell loop

```
grep --null -rslZ "foo" | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file
    do 
        sed -i -- "s/foo/bar/g" "$file"
    done
```

Comment: So no way to make it work with `for..in..do..done`  ?

Comment: @slhck Thanks.  I updated the answer to use `--null` which is supported by both GNU and [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep).   The [OpenBSD man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/egrep.1?query=grep) however does not list any support for NUL.

Comment: @rahmanisback No.  You can safely forget about `for` for looping over filenames with spaces.

Comment: @rahmanisback No, that's an anti-pattern. When you're dealing with files, it only works properly on glob expansions, e.g. `for f in *.txt`. Don't try to do anything fancy there—it'll almost certainly fail.

Comment: For standard `grep`s and the like: `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -sl 'foo' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/g' --`

Comment: @lcd047 That's not true. `touch "foo bar"; for f in *; do some-command "$f"; done`. That's pretty easy.

Comment: @rahmanisback How about a `while` loop instead?  See updated answer for an example.

Comment: @slhck Ok.  You can safely forget about it for most non-trivial cases.  Better now? :)

Answer (score 0):

> You can safely forget about for for looping over filenames with spaces.

Not necessarily...

```
IFS=$'\n' && for NAV in `ps aux | egrep -o 'Google Chrome' | sort | uniq`; do
   open -a "$NAV" http://www.google.com
done
```